# Accessing components of data from the "." (dot) operator with magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm not clear on how to apply functions to components of data using the dot (".") with magrittr such as columns of a data from or items in a list.

Example:

```
> data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20) %>% .$y
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

It seems that accessing the data should work the same as applying a function to it, but it does not:

```
> data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20) %>% min(.$y)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data.frame will be passed as the first parameter unless a lone dot is placed somewhere else in the call.

```
data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20) %>% min(.$y)
```

is the same as

```
dd <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
min(dd, dd$y)
# [1] 1
```

[This is by design](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/30).

You would have to use a code block

```
data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20) %>% {min(.$y)}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm curious, then, why data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20) %>% .$y doesn't give something like data.frame(dd, dd$y).  Also, doesn't my first example contain a "lone dot placed somewhere else in the call"?

Comment: Because `.$y` is equivalent to  `'$'(., y)` which is already putting the data.frame where you want it. You could also use `%>% '$'(y)` without the dot. It's really more about not going into nested calls than a "lone dot" so I was being a bit imprecise there.

Comment: @jzadra Btw, there's some esoterics associated with how magrittr behaves when `.` appears explicitly as an argument to the function. Namely, if it is a freestanding argument to the function (as MrFlick showed is the case in your example), then the dot is not additionally given as the first argument. So, for example `"A" %>% setNames(.)` is not equivalent to `setNames("A", "A")` and in fact fails. https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/128 (Oh, just noticed MrFlick edited the comment to cover that. Anywho, I'll leave this comment here.)

Comment: For this exampe, you may want to use : `data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20) %$% min(y)`